# Go mongo-driver cannot connect to mongodb container

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose

I am using a simple go CRUD api that uses MongoDB and moving it to docker containers. I cannot connect to the MongoDB for some reason. After researching I cannot find a solution.

I have tried:

- Exposing/publishing ports, so I can use the container name instead of 'mongodb:localhost:27017/' when trying to connect to the client.
- I have also removed any network config in my compose.yml file so that there is no network confusion.

This is my compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'
    
services:
    mongodb:
      image: mongo:4.0.4
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
      
    mongo_todo:
      build: ./mongo_todo
      ports: 
        - 3000:3000
      depends_on:
        - mongodb
      
    go_todo:
    build: ./go_todo
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - mongo_todo
```

This is my mongo_todo Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.14
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

EXPOSE 80
```

And this is how I am trying to connect to the client:

```
// Set client options
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://mongodb:27017")

// Connect to MongoDB
Client, _ = mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

// Check the connection
err := Client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

The program is logging a Fatal error when trying to ping the client to check the connection.

Log output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x2e0 pc=0x9a798c]
goroutine 1 [running]:
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Client).Ping(0x0, 0xd61e20, 0xc000028030, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0)
/go/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/client.go:229 +0x21c
main.main()
/go/src/app/main.go:30 +0x16f
```

I understand that it is some kind of networking issue but I have no idea why it is not working and I have a feeling that there's something simple that I am missing.

Please ask me for more information if needed and thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I can ping the hostname mongodb from my go_todo container so not sure if it is a network issue.

Comment: Did you configure mongod to listen on an IP other than localhost?

Comment: Hi Joe, not as far as I am aware I've just kept it default.

Comment: The default is to only listen on 127.0.0.1

Comment: That's what I thought. Does this not then resolve to the local host of the 'mongodb' container: `// Set client options
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://mongodb:27017"`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is confusing a bit (read: annoying) part of using docker-compose.

The service called `mongodb` is not what the container name is that you set your `ApplyURI` to. docker-compose prefixes a "project name" to the container name.

Run a `docker ps` and look for the column '**NAMES**' (should be the last one). Use the name of your mongodb instance for the URI host, and it should connect.

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid and clearly a docker noob.

I thought that `docker-compose up` rebuilt my container images but it doesn't and so my changes were not being used.

Thanks you for your comments though I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You should debug the code and check which object is Nil. Maybe you are calling method on Nil object.

I will suggest you to explicitly create a `Docker network` and attach your MongoDB docker instance and your application to it. Then access your MongoDB using container name. I also faced the connection issue and I resolved that using `Docker network`.

As **@CenterOrbit** suggested, name your containers explicitly otherwise docker will give it a random name, and you won't be able to connect to MongoDB.